# How to approximate Gamma Function when inputting decimals?

Tags: approximation, gamma-function

I was writing some code on approximating the gamma function using Stirling's method, but as far as I know it is only applicable for integer arguments. Does anyone know of another that can take decimals as arguments? Thanks

Comment: You could always use the fact that $\Gamma(z)= \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} \;dt$ and apply any numerical analysis technique of approximating this improper integral to your desired level of accuracy. The approximation $\Gamma(z+1) \sim \sqrt{2\pi x} (x/e)^x$ is asymptotically correct, i.e. "valid" for large $x$ but is weaker than just numerically approximating the integral as you fail to have predictable control of the error.

Comment: You might also see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation

Comment: You can apply Stirling approximation for $\Gamma(x)$ for any real value of $x$. It is just an algebraic expression.

Comment: Little remark: "when imputing decimals (for the "argument")" sounds very "computer science" ; an alternative expression would be "for real values of the variable".

Comment: @JeanMarie: The "computer science" phrasing would be `float`s or `double`s.  *Decimal* arithmetic is for accountants.

Comment: @Dan Accurate remark !

Comment: @ChiSquare Did any of us answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. For some reason I thought that I couldn’t comment after I asked my question.

Comment: @ChiSquare In that case you can upvote the answers that you found useful and accept the one you found the most useful. To accept an answer, click on the ✓ symbol on the left-side of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler and clearer if you use Stirling approximation as
$$\log (\Gamma (x))=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\log (2 \pi
   )\right)+\frac{1}{12 x}-\frac{1}{360 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$ and then
$$\Gamma (x)=e^{\log (\Gamma (x)) }$$

You can use any real number.

Answer (score 1):

One can derive many variants of the Stirling approximation. One variant that I have found useful for practical computation is
$$\Gamma(x) \approx \sqrt{2\pi}\exp\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln x-x\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{12x}+\frac{1}{288x^2}-\ldots\right)$$

The Digital Library of Mathematical Functions lists this in [§5.11(i) Poincaré-Type Expansions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11), provides additional terms, and includes pointers to publications by Wrench and Spira that give even more terms.

For numerical computation it is important to remember that $\exp$ magnifies errors in its argument. Achieving fully accurate results for any given target precision therefore requires computing the argument to $\exp$ and in particular $\ln x$ to *more than* the target precision. Also, the approximation above will not deliver very accurate results for arguments near zero. An approximation $\frac{1}{xp(x)}$ could be used for that, where $p$ is a polynomial: a series approximation of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$ around zero. For negative arguments the well-known [reflection formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5) can be used.

When creating an implementation for a specific floating-point format, one typically replaces series expansions with the related minimax approximations. Standard tools like Maple and Mathematica have built-in facilities to generate these, or one can use the open-source [Sollya tool](https://www.sollya.org/), in particular its `fpminimax` command.

I have recently learned that there is a formalization of the above approach due to Nico Temme. The first appearance of this I can find is in N. M. Temme, "A set of algorithms for the incomplete gamma functions," *Probability in the Engineering and Informational Sciences,* Vol. 8, No. 2, April 1994, pp. 291-307, where $\Gamma(x) = \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-x}x^{x-\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma^{\star}(x), x\gt0$, and where $\Gamma^{\star}$ is called the "tempered gamma function". Next it appeared in Amparo Gil, Javier Segura, and Nico M. Temme, *Numerical Methods for Special Functions,* SIAM 2007, p. 243 as $\Gamma^{\star}(a)=\sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi}}e^{a}a^{-a}\Gamma(a), a > 0$. More recently the name of $\Gamma^{\star}$ was changed to "regulated gamma function" in Amparo Gil, Javier Segura, and Nico M. Temme, "GammaCHI: a package for the inversion and computation of the gamma and chi-square cumulative distribution functions (central and noncentral)," *Computer Physics Communications*, Vol. 191, June 2015, pp. 132-139. In the authors' [GNSTLIB library](https://personales.unican.es/segurajj/gnstlib/) this function is included as `gammastar`.

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotic expansions of the gamma function work for real (and complex) variable as well. For each $N\geq 1$, let us write
$$
\Gamma (z) = \sqrt {2\pi } z^{z - 1/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - z} \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {( - 1)^n \frac{{\gamma _n }}{{z^n }}}  + R_N (z)} \right)
$$
and
$$
\log \Gamma (z) = \tfrac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) + \left( {z - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log z - z + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{{B_{2n} }}{{2n(2n - 1)z^{2n - 1} }}}  + \widetilde R_N (z).
$$
Here $\gamma_n$ denote the so-called Stirling coefficients and $B_n$ denote the [Bernoulli numbers](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2). The former may be computed via the recurrence relations
$$
\gamma _{2n - 1}  =  - \frac{1}{{2n - 1}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{2k}}\gamma _{2n - 2k} } ,\quad \gamma _{2n}  =  - \frac{1}{{2n}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{2k}}\gamma _{2n - 2k + 1} } 
$$
for $n\geq 1$ with $\gamma_0=1$ (see [this](https://doi.org/10.2307/2004538) paper). The remainder terms satisfy the bounds
$$
\left |R_N(z) \right |  \le \left(\frac{\left |\gamma_N \right |}{|z|^N} + \frac{\left |\gamma_{N+1} \right |}{|z|^{N+1}}\right)\times
    \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if }\; |\arg z| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}, \\
      |\csc(2\arg z)| & \text{ if }\; \frac{\pi}{4} < |\arg z| < \frac{\pi}{2},
    \end{cases}
$$
and
$$
|\widetilde R_N (z)| \le \frac{\left| B_{2N} \right|}{2N(2N - 1)\left| z \right|^{2N - 1} } \\ \times \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } \; \left|\arg z\right| \leq \tfrac{\pi}{4}, \\ \min \!\big(\left| \csc (2\arg z) \right|,\tfrac{1}{2}\chi (2N - 1) + 1\big) & \text{ if } \; \tfrac{\pi}{4} < \left|\arg z\right| \leq \tfrac{\pi}{2}, \\ \cfrac{\sqrt {2\pi (2N - 1)} }{2\left| \sin (\arg z) \right|^{2N - 1} } + \tfrac{1}{2}\chi (2N - 1) + 1 & \text{ if } \; \tfrac{\pi}{2} < \left|\arg z\right| < \pi. \end{cases}
$$
Here $\chi(p)=\sqrt \pi  \Gamma \big( \frac{p}{2} + 1 \big)/\Gamma \big( \frac{p}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \big)<\sqrt{\frac{\pi(p+1)}{2}}$ with any $p>0$. See [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0308210513001558) and [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspa.2017.0363). We also have
$$
\left| {R_N (z)} \right| \le \left( {\sqrt N  + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\frac{{(1 + \zeta (N))\Gamma (N)}}{{(2\pi )^{N + 1} \left| z \right|^N }}
$$
for $N\geq 2$ and $|\arg z|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, with $\zeta$ being the Riemann zeta function. Again, see [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0308210513001558).

Other approximations include the [Lánczos approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation) and the [Spouge approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spouge%27s_approximation).